# Is everything provided by TR1 now available in C++14 and easy to make use of?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, tr1

We expect that converting old sources from using TR1, to not using it, will be straightforward work such as fixing #includes, changing a few names, and patching the build system, but cannot find a definitive statement that this is so for everything in TR1.

I know C++14 through language enhancements and a new standard library now provides many nice things that were in TR1. Even C++11 took over quite a lot from TR1.

But have *all* things in TR1 been made available as language and library features?   What in TR1 hasn't been eaten by C++14? (Things we don't use, we hope.)

As for TR1 features now in C++14, do any require more effort than simple name changes?

Comment: Are you using the mathematical special functions?  Uncertain if they all got into C++14.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There were a lot of things in tr1, there were a lot of things in C++11. You could go one by one through the features you use and see what happened to them?

Comment: @Barry It is broad, but I'd argue not too broad.  While tr1 is large, the set of things that are not nearly identical and in C++14 will be small (if somewhat difficult to find).

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, but the index is 12 pages long... The merged set might be small, but that's still a lot to sift through to find the answer.

Comment: @Barry "Too broad" is about the *answer*  being too broad, not the work to *find the answer* will be too broad.  I'd consider this a hard question, not a too broad one.

Comment: I agree that this question is reasonable. Yes it is broad, But to answer the question "no" requires just one person to have at some point identified just one thing that didn't make it into the standard. Ultimately though, the answer is that many minor tweaks were made between TR1 and c++11 or c++14, especially in detailed behaviour. Indeed C++14 contains a couple of bug fixes for C++11 so either way round they can't match TR1 in detailed behaviour. Equally, I'm surprised there isn't a cross-reference somewhere.

Comment: On the other hand, C++14 (perhaps C++17) is probably as good as it is going to get for TR1-inspired features. C++20 looks to be a new beast altogether! So it is either now or never!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*C++ Technical Report 1* (TR1) is the common name for [ISO/IEC TR 19768](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf), C++ Library Extensions, which was a document proposing additions to the C++ standard library for the C++03 language standard. The additions include regular expressions, smart pointers, hash tables, and random number generators. TR1 was not a standard itself, but rather a draft document. However, **most of its proposals became part of the later official standard, C++11**. Before C++11 was standardized, vendors used this document as a guide to create extensions [1].

Generally, most of the features from TR1 passed to C++11, except some minor exceptions and some renamings in `<random>` header, shown below:

[**`<random>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

- `variate_generator` didn't make it.
- `linear_congruential` made it as [`linear_congruential_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine)
- `mersenne_twister` made it as [`mersenne_twister_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)
- `subtract_with_carry` made it as [`subtract_with_carry_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/subtract_with_carry_engine)
- `subtract_with_carry_01` didn't make it.
- `discard_block` made it as [`discard_block_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discard_block_engine)
- `xor_combine` didn't make it.
- `uniform_int` made it as [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)
- `uniform_real` made it as [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real)

Also note that from the `<type_traits>` header in C++17 [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) was replaced with [`invoke_result`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

[1]: [C++ Technical Report 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1)

Comment: What are the minor exceptions?  Are they also in random?

Comment: @Yakk sorry if is not clear enough, minor exceptions and renamings go both for `<random>`.